# Introduction to circuit complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

The books I'm reading on complexity theory primarily are about complexity of decision problems by Turing machines.

I'm interested in computational complexity of circuits, both boolean and continuous circuits (I'm not sure to what extent there is a complexity theory of continuous circuits). Do you know of a good introductory text for this?

Comment: You can try Jukna's Boolean function complexity.